# PyTorch Geometric how to calculate eigenvector centrality?

Tags: pytorch, networkx, generative-adversarial-network, autograd, pytorch-geometric

I have GAN for a graph prediction task in which there are `torch_geometric.nn.NNConv` layers. I want to add eigenvector centrality difference between ground-truth and predicted graph to my loss function. To calculate eigenvector centrality, I intended to use `eigenvector_centrality` function from `NetworkX` library. However, this function requires input to be a `NetworkX` graph which also requires to convert my `torch.tensor` outputted from Generator network to `numpy.array`. So, I need to `detach()` the gradient which will cause PyTorch to lose all gradient tracking. Thus, how can I properly implement a eigenvector centrality for my loss function? Thanks.